# How to correctly implement the if-else condition in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have XML in which there is a ContactRecords node:

```
<Organisations>
<Organisation>
<Tag1>ValueElementTag1</Tag1>
<Tag2>ValueElementTag2</Tag2>
<Tag3>ValueElementTag3</Tag3>
<ContactRecords>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>AAAAA</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueAAAAA</ContactValue>
                <Address xmlns="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <AdrTag1 xsi:type="Adr">Example1</AdrTag1>
                    <AdrTag2>Example2</AdrTag2>
                </Address>
            </item>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>BBBBB</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueBBBBB</ContactValue>
                <Address xmlns="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <AdrTag1 xsi:type="Adr">Example1</AdrTag1>
                    <AdrTag2>Example2</AdrTag2>
                </Address>
            </item>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>CCCCC</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueCCCCC</ContactValue>
            </item>
</ContactRecords>
</Organisation>
<Organisation>
<Tag1>ValueElementTag1</Tag1>
<Tag2>ValueElementTag2</Tag2>
<Tag3>ValueElementTag3</Tag3>
<ContactRecords>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>AAAAA</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueAAAAA</ContactValue>
                <Address xmlns="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                    
                    <AdrTag1 xsi:type="Adr">Example1</AdrTag1>
                    <AdrTag2>Example2</AdrTag2>
                </Address>
            </item>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>BBBBB</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueBBBBB</ContactValue>
                <Address xmlns="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <AdrTag1 xsi:type="Adr">Example1</AdrTag1>
                    <AdrTag2>Example2</AdrTag2>
                </Address>
            </item>
            <item>
                <ContactRecordType>CCCCC</ContactRecordType>
                <ContactValue>ValueCCCCC</ContactValue>
            </item>
</ContactRecords>
</Organisation>
</Organisations>
```

I am writing an XSLT which has a handling of a ContactRecords node:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/"> 


<xsl:element name="Organisations">
    <xsl:for-each select="Organisations/Organisation">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
              <xsl:for-each select="*[not(name()='ContactRecords')]">
                   <xsl:copy select="*">
                       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                   </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="ContactRecords/item">
                <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="Address">
                         <h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
                         <h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              ​​</xsl:for-each>
      ​</xsl:element>
   ​</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I am now getting the following result:

```
<h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
<h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
​​<h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
```

I expect to receive:

```
<h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
<h2>mooooooooooooo</h2>
​​<h2>dooooooooooooo</h2>
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I explain the algorithm in words, then I need the following: if there is an Address element in the item element, then we do logic number 1. If there is no Address element in the item element, then we do logic number 2.

If we describe the algorithm in pseudocode, then this is how:

```
if (item.includes(Address)) {
 do logic #1
} else {
 do logic #2
}
```

UPD1: Updated XML and XSLT code
UPD2: Add namespaces in tags Address (maybe the reason is in them)

Comment: Your input sample is not even well-formed so we don't know how a minimal but complete sample looks but at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS7p your code with a corrected input sample looks fine.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I have completed the XML and XSLT code as it looks now

Comment: @MartinHonnen, add namespaces in tags Address (maybe the reason is in them)

Comment: Yes, if the element is in a namespace then the test `Address` doesn't test it as it tests for elements named `Address` in *no* namespace. So in your stylesheet declare e.g. `xmlns:ci="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo"` and use `ci:Address` in the check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Address` element is in a namespace, so your test:

```
<xsl:when test="Address">
```

returns `false` every time. Try it this way (minimized to the current problem):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.v8.1c.ru/ssl/contactinfo"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Organisations"> 
    <Organisations>
        <xsl:for-each select="Organisation">
            <xsl:copy>
                <!-- omitted -->
                <xsl:for-each select="ContactRecords/item">
                    <h2>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="ns0:Address">mooooooooooooo</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>dooooooooooooo</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </h2>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </Organisations>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```